# Checking network status

Tags: swift, networking

I have this slightly popular Swift library called [IJReachability](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/IJReachability) up on Github. It checks the network connection status. Due to my office workload I've been very busy in the past few months so I couldn't attend to the project and keep in touch with the folks who are contributing.

Now I'm back and hoping to dust off the project, update to Swift 2 (probably still keep the 1.2 version in a separate branch) and activly participate on developing it.

The project was originally written in Swift 1.2:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public enum IJReachabilityType {
    case WWAN,
    WiFi,
    NotConnected
}

public class IJReachability {

    public class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }

    public class func isConnectedToNetworkOfType() -> IJReachabilityType {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return .NotConnected
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let isWWAN = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)) != 0

        if(isReachable && isWWAN){
            return .WWAN
        }
        if(isReachable && !isWWAN){
            return .WiFi
        }

        return .NotConnected
    }

}
```

One method checks if you're currently connected to network or not and the other one returns the type of the connection. And as you can see there is quite a bit of code duplication.

I've updated the project to Swift 2 with the help of the pull requests I got:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration


let ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification = "ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification"

enum ReachabilityType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case WWAN
    case WiFi
    case NotConnected

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .WWAN: return "WWAN"
        case .WiFi: return "WiFi"
        case .NotConnected: return "NotConnected"
        }
    }
}

enum ReachabilityStatus: CustomStringConvertible  {
    case Offline
    case Online
    case Unknown

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Offline: return "Offline"
        case .Online: return "Online"
        case .Unknown: return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}

public class Reach {

    func connectedToNetwork() -> (status: ReachabilityStatus, type: ReachabilityType) {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else {
            return (status: .Offline, type: .NotConnected)
        }

        var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return (status: .Offline, type: .NotConnected)
        }

        let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
        let isWWAN = flags.contains(.IsWWAN)

        if isReachable && isWWAN {
            return (status: .Online, type: .WWAN)
        }

        if isReachable && !isWWAN {
            return (status: .Online, type: .WiFi)
        }

        return (status: .Offline, type: .NotConnected)
    }


    func monitorReachabilityChanges() {
        let host = "google.com"
        var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
        let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
            var status: ReachabilityStatus!
            var type: ReachabilityType!

            let connectionRequired = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
            let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
            let isWWAN = flags.contains(.IsWWAN)

            if !connectionRequired && flags.contains(.Reachable) {
                if isReachable && isWWAN {
                    status = .Online
                    type = .WWAN
                }

                if isReachable && !isWWAN {
                    status = .Online
                    type = .WiFi
                }
            } else {
                status =  .Offline
                type = .NotConnected
            }

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification,
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["Status": status.description, "Type": type.description])

            }, &context)

        SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
    }

}
```

But I did something different. Instead of having two functions for the network status and the type, I consolidated the functionality of both functions into one. I also added a new function to monitor the network connectivity in the background (this wasn't possible in Swift 1.2 due to language limitations).

I have two questions:

1. The `connectedToNetwork()` function returns a tuple packing both the status and type. Is this a good way to do this? Even though this is possible, I've never seen tuples used much in Apple and third party frameworks/libraries.
2. There is still some code duplication. Specifically checking the `flags` variable for what it contains. I'm not sure how to refactor this in an optimal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a tuple as return type is generally fine. I haven't seen it much 
either in Apple's frameworks, the only one that I know of at present
is the `String` method

```
public static func fromCStringRepairingIllFormedUTF8(cs: UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> (String?, hadError: Bool)
```

In your particular case however, I think there is a better way.
The reachability *type* is only relevant if the *status* is `.Online`, and not all type/status
combinations make sense.

I would therefore *include* the type into the status by
using enums with *associated values*:

```
enum ReachabilityType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case WWAN
    case WiFi
    // No case NotConnected anymore.

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .WWAN: return "WWAN"
        case .WiFi: return "WiFi"
        }
    }
}

enum ReachabilityStatus: CustomStringConvertible  {
    case Offline
    case Online(ReachabilityType) // Type as an associated value.
    case Unknown

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Offline: return "Offline"
        case .Online(let type): return "Online(\(type))"
        case .Unknown: return "Unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `connectedToNetwork()` function should return a `ReachabilityStatus`, and
possible values are: `.Unknown`, `.Offline`, `.Online(.WWAN)`
and `.Online(.WiFi)`. A better name for that function might be
`connectionStatus()`.

The `.Unknown` status is currently not used at all. You might return
that if the status could not be determined (e.g. retrieving the
flags failed).

The code duplication for evaluating the flags can be solved by
defining an (perhaps private) init method of `ReachabilityStatus` which
takes an `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` parameter:

```
extension ReachabilityStatus {
    private init(reachabilityFlags flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) {
        let connectionRequired = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
        let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
        let isWWAN = flags.contains(.IsWWAN)

        if !connectionRequired && isReachable {
            if isWWAN {
                self = .Online(.WWAN)
            } else {
                self = .Online(.WiFi)
            }
        } else {
            self =  .Offline
        }
    }
}
```

so that your function would now look like this:

```
func connectionStatus() -> ReachabilityStatus {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        return .Unknown
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return .Unknown
    }
    return ReachabilityStatus(reachabilityFlags: flags)
}
```

*More remarks:* Instead of using the `NSNotificationCenter`
you could pass a *closure* as a callback to the `monitorReachabilityChanges()` function. That would save you from 
the hassle to wrap (and later unwrap) the status into some Objective-C
compatible type. (**Added:** However, that would require more changes
because a C callback cannot capture context. See [Swift 2 - UnsafeMutablePointer to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object) for a possible solution.)

Note also that you need some method to *stop* the monitoring, i.e.
to unregister the reachability from the run loop.

All information get be retrieved from this single `ReachabilityStatus` 
value with the associated `ReachabilityType`. You can check
for all possible values with a switch statement:

```
switch status {
case .Unknown, .Offline:
    print("not connected")
case .Online(.WWAN):
    print("connected via WWan")
case .Online(.WiFi):
    print("connected via WiFi")
}
```

or use if/case with pattern matching to check for a certain state:

```
if case .Online = status  {
    print("online")
} else {
    print("offline")
}

if case .Online(.WiFi) = status {
    print("connected via WiFi")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the response. That does indeed resolve all the duplication issues. But what if you need to know not only the status but the type of the connection too? I know it's returned from the description property but that's as a string. You cannot compare it with the enum values, right?

Comment: @Isuru: See updated answer ...

Comment: Thanks for including more info. I tried updating the `monitorReachabilityChanges()` function adding a closure. Here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/qVd1Xh42). But when I callback from inside the `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` closure, I get the error **A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context**.

Comment: @Isuru: I see. The problem is that a C callback cannot capture context (which I overlooked when writing my first remark). The solution is to use a pure C callback and passing context to it via opaque pointers. My suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object made it into another slightly popular Swift library: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Reachability.swift

Comment: Okay I modified the class a little. I also added a method to stop the monitoring as you suggested. [Code](http://pastebin.com/P5PHwvp1). I get the error **attempt to create an Unmanaged instance from a null pointer** when creating the `obj` variable inside the `callback` function though.

Comment: @Isuru:  `context.info` is what is passed as `pointer` to the callback, and that is null because you haven't assigned anything to it.

Comment: I added the line `context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())` after initializing the `context` variable. But now I get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error at the line where I declare the `obj` variable value.

Comment: @Isuru: I think this discussing is going off-topic for *this* Q&A. I tried to answer your main two questions, and made some additional suggestions. If you  prefer it I can remove that part from my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. No need to remove. More info is never a harm. Thanks.